# How to test http request block with cedar in IOS

Tags: ios, cedar-bdd

I want to test a class named BookService with a method to get a list of book info.
What should I do to coverage both  success block and failure block ?
Here is my method code:

```
-(void)getRequestWithURL:(NSString *)urlStr withKey:(NSString *)keyWord completion:(void (^)(NSMutableArray *data))complete{
if(manager==nil)
    manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
NSLog(@"%@",keyWord);
NSMutableArray *datas = [NSMutableArray new];
NSDictionary *dict=@{
                     @"q":keyWord,
                     @"count":@10
                     };

[manager GET:urlStr parameters:dict progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress) {} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject){
    //NSMutableArray *books=[NSMutableArray new];
    NSArray *json= responseObject[@"books"];

    for(id book in json){
        BookInfo *b = [[BookInfo alloc]initWithJson:book];
        NSLog(@"%@",b.author[0]);
        [datas addObject:b];
    }
    complete(datas);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error){
    NSLog(@"返回失败");
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
    complete(nil);
}];
```

}

And here is my test code with cedar

SPEC_BEGIN(BookServiceSpec)

`describe(@"BookService", ^{
__block BookService *bookService;
__block AFHTTPSessionManager *manager;
__block UITableView *tableView;
__block NSMutableArray *data;
__block NSString *key;
__block NSString *url;

beforeEach(^{
    tableView = [[UITableView alloc]init];

    data = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
});


describe(@"test bookService", ^{

    context(@"get book success", ^{
        beforeEach(^{
            manager = fake_for([AFHTTPSessionManager class]);
            manager stub_method(@selector(GET:parameters:progress:success:failure:));
            bookService = [[BookService alloc]initWithManager:manager];

            url = @"https://api.douban.com/v2/book/search";
            key=@"java";
            //bookService stub_method(@selector(getRequestWithURL:withKey:completion:));

        });
        it(@"should manager not be nil", ^{
            [bookService getRequestWithURL:url withKey:key completion:^(NSMutableArray *data) {
                bookService should have_received("getRequestWithURL:withKey:completion");
            }];
        });  
    });`

SPEC_END

Comment: Easiest is use some mocking library like Mockingjay to create stub for your response, then can get with the exact response you wanted to happen

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I have to use cedar and I don't know how to mock response really because there is not so many samples in wiki.So did you mean that I can use other mocking library to test this method?